# Hyperconnected components may not be disjoint

Tags: general-topology

A topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is *hyperconnected*, if $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$ for each $U, V \in \mathcal{T} \setminus \{\emptyset\}$. A *hyperconnected component*, or a *hypercomponent*, is a subset-maximal hyperconnected subset. [Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconnected_space) that hypercomponents may not be disjoint. Can you give an example of a space where the hypercomponents are not disjoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and
$$\tau =\{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\},X, \emptyset\}.$$
Then subspaces $\{1,3\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ are hyperconnected, but $X$ isn't. So they are hyperconnected, maximal and not disjoint.

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing the example from Esgeriath, consider the [excluded point topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excluded_point_topology) on a set $X$ with a particular point $p\in X$ and with $X$ having at least three elements.  All the points $x\ne p$ are isolated in $X$ and $X$ is the only nbhd of $p$.

If a subset of $X$ is hyperconnected, it can contain at most one point different from $p$ (otherwise you would get two singleton open sets not intersecting each other).  On the other hand, if $x\ne p$, the subspace $\{p,x\}$ is isomorphic to the [Sierpiński space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space), which is hyperconnected.  So the hyperconnected components are exactly the sets $\{p,x\}$ with $x\ne p$.  Note that they all intersect in $p$.